# Best approach to upload volume to repository

Tags: python, docker, vscode-devcontainer

I'm developing an API rest using `Python` and `Flask` in a `Docker image`. In developing using the feature `Remote-Containers` from `VS Code` (in windows, with Docker Desktop installed).

This API uses a volume created locally in my pc. I connect the volume when the VSCode open the container. My `.devcontainer.json`

```json
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",
    "context": "..",  
    "dockerFile": "../dockerfile",
    "settings": {
      "git.path": "/usr/bin/git"
    },
    "extensions": [
      "mhutchie.git-graph",
      "eamodio.gitlens",
  
      "tht13.python",
      "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
      "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"
    ],
    "runArgs": ["-v", "persisted-dictionaries:/dictionaries/data"]
}
```

My `dockerfile` (just in case)

```
FROM python

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_ENV=development

EXPOSE 5001:5000

CMD ["flask", "run", "-h" , "0.0.0.0"]
```

I'm newbie to this kind of working an development, and the official documentation can be a bit overwhelming, so I have a few questions:

- I want to upload this to a repository, but I don't known how to upload the volume. Is there a way to create, if not exists, the volume? This is thinking in new people developing and don't have a volume created (until we have a remote volume). What I want is, with a simple git clone, be able to have the full develop environment, if is possible.
- Am I using the 'best' way to connect my volume to my `devcontainer`? Reading a lot of questions, this one is the one that works for me, but i don't know the implications.
- Taking advantage of this question, is there a better way to do this? I have followed a lot of tutorials, and my project is a mix of some tutorials.
- Should I change from `Dockerfile` to `Docker-compose` ? It seems that with `docker-compose` is 'easier'.

Sorry if the questions are a bit odd, but i'm new to all of this and i don't know if i'm on the right path. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For development, a [Python virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments) might be much simpler than trying to force Docker into your development flow.  For production, you might consider if you can store the data in an external database; managing "files" or "volumes" in Docker can become surprisingly tricky.

Comment: "I don't known how to upload the volume"—typically, you wouldn't. Data usually doesn't belong in your repository. What are you storing there, and why are you trying to commit it? (The fact that it's a volume is mostly irrelevant.)

Comment: It's a volume where I  download some files in order to have the full functionality in the API. I used a volume because I don't want to download all the required files all the times I build the image, so this  seems (to me, probably there is a better approach) a finest way to have a place where I can store my files without create a database..